# My C++ code will never be executed past the else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

just starting out here. Xcode is telling me this "code will never be executed on the first line within the else statement and I don't know what to do about it.

I am trying to make it so that if the user's input is not one the four options in the switch statement it defaults to the third option. Please help.

```
int lengthoption;
std::cout << "Please select an option for the length of your loan based on the following options: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "1. 3 years" <<std::endl;
std::cout << "2. 4 years" <<std::endl;
std::cout << "3. 5 years" <<std::endl;
std::cout << "4. 6 years" <<std::endl;
std::cin >> lengthoption;


double NumberofPayments;
if (lengthoption == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)
{
    switch (lengthoption)
    {
        case 1:
            NumberofPayments = 36;
            std::cout << "You chose a 3 year loan with a total of " << NumberofPayments << " monthly payments." << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            NumberofPayments = 48;
            std::cout << "You chose a 4 year loan with a total of " << NumberofPayments << " monthly payments." << std::endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            NumberofPayments = 60;
            std::cout << "You chose a 5 year loan with a total of " << NumberofPayments << " monthly payments." << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            NumberofPayments = 72;
            std::cout << "You chose a 6 year loan with a total of " << NumberofPayments << " monthly payments." << std::endl;
    }
}

else
{
    ***NumberofPayments = 60;***
    std::cout << "You chose a 5 year loan with a total of " << NumberofPayments << " monthly payments." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to check in a c++ book the syntax of "if" and how it works when you check different value at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (lengthoption == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)
```

2 evaluates to true, therefor the condition is always true.

You have to put the full boolean expression between each `||` as such:

```
if (lengthoption == 1 || 
    lengthoption == 2 || 
    lengthoption == 3 || 
    lengthoption == 4)
```

or perhaps

```
if (lengthoption >= 1 && lengthoption <= 4)
```